# How to add huge number of elements from array to MySQL using Sequleize in Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

This is the operation going on in my method

```
 if (result) {
                const csvdata = result.body;
                var csvarray = csvdata.split('\n')  //array details are shown below

                for (var i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
                    const eachdata = csvarray[i];
                    var symbolarray = eachdata.split(",");
                    const obj = {
                        "instrument_token": symbolarray[0],
                        "exchange_token": symbolarray[1],
                        "tradingsymbol": symbolarray[2],
                        "name": symbolarray[3],
                        "last_price": symbolarray[4],
                        "expiry": symbolarray[5],
                        "strike": symbolarray[6],
                        "tick_size": symbolarray[7],
                        "lot_size": symbolarray[8],
                        "instrument_type": symbolarray[9],
                        "segment": symbolarray[10],
                        "exchange": symbolarray[11]
                    }

                    db.symboltable.create(obj)
                        .then((response) => {
                            console.log("added to symbol table")
                        })
                        .catch((err) => {
                            console.log(err)
                        })
}
```

csvarray contains elements like :

```
[
 "267556358,1045142,EURINR20AUGFUT,\"EURINR\",0,2020-08-27,0,0.0025,1,FUT,BCD-FUT,BCD",
 "268660998,1049457,EURINR20DECFUT,\"EURINR\",0,2020-12-29,0,0.0025,1,FUT,BCD-FUT,BCD",
 "266440966,1040785,EURINR20JULFUT,\"EURINR\",0,2020-07-29,0,0.0025,1,FUT,BCD-FUT,BCD",
 "266073606,1039350,EURINR20JUNFUT,\"EURINR\",0,2020-06-26,0,0.0025,1,FUT,BCD-FUT,BCD",
]
```

it contains thousands of similar elements  and when the methods calls, i am getting an error like :

```
D:\MEAN\node projects\Trade\controllers\apicontroller.js:135
                    var symbolarray = eachdata.split(",");
                                               ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at Request._callback (D:\MEAN\node projects\Trade\controllers\apicontroller.js:135:48)
    at Request.self.callback (D:\MEAN\node projects\Trade\node_modules\postman-request\request.js:268:12)
    at Request.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at Request.<anonymous> (D:\MEAN\node projects\Trade\node_modules\postman-request\request.js:1489:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (D:\MEAN\node projects\Trade\node_modules\postman-request\request.js:1360:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:417:28)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:323:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1204:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

can anyone get me out from this issue

Comment: Your array is full of CSV records. *Don't* invent your own CSV parser; fully debugged ones have thousands of lines of code in them, really. What looks simple is not simple. Try this. https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv

Comment: array index is zero based, so change the loop start from 0 instead of 1